# C# Object suddenly null

Tags: c#, huffman-code

I've searched so long and hard for this and now I'm at road's end. I've had this issue with more than this project, but I ended up scrapping the others. I have a code (C#) which is basically me trying to do Huffman tree. At one point I do this ("nodeList" is List(Node)):

```
Node node = new Node(nodeList[0], nodeList[1]);
nodeList.Add(node); // Adds a new node which includes two subnodes.

// Remove nodes from list (as they are now included in another node)
nodeList.RemoveAt(0);
nodeList.RemoveAt(1);
```

And the constructors in use here is:

```
// Constructor that takes nodes
public Node(Node left, Node right)
{
   leftNode = new Node(left);
   rightNode = new Node(right);
}

// Constructor that only takes 1 single node
public Node(Node copy)
{
   rightNode = copy.rightNode;
   leftNode = copy.leftNode;
   unencodedBits = copy.unencodedBits;
   encodingValue = copy.encodingValue;
   positions = copy.positions;
}
```

I did the second constructor as a hope that it would fix my problem (thinking that removing the node from the list maybe nulled it out.) (all of the values in my Node-class is on the right side of the second constructor.)

The problem: After doing the second "RemoveAt" the Node will no longer contain the two nodes. And I can not understand why. What do I have to do to prevent this from happening and why does it happen (so I can understand similar cases in the future)?

I probably forgot to include some vital information; If I did, please tell me. And thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Anytime you have a question about what the code is doing, it helps to set breakpoints and then step through the code. You'll be able to see what each method call is doing.

Comment: I know what each method is calling. I wrote the methods (except for RemoveAt, but I don't have a way of checking what that does.) I'm just wondering why it suddenly nulls out my objects (some objects anyway, not all.)

Comment: You _do_ have a way of checking to see what RemoveAt does. Like I said, set a breakpoint and watch your nodeList object as you step through it. You'll see exactly the effect that RemoveAt has on it.

Comment: What exactly is null?

Comment: @Morten242 what do you mean by you don't have a way to check what it does? Using the debugger you can see what happens before & after the method is called... Unless you are on a special kind of environment that you forgot to mention...

Comment: @BrunoLM I was thinking more along the lines of seeing the code it executes. I did check the difference from before and after, but the only unique thing about the objects were whether or not they contained any subnodes, so my error passed me by.

Comment: @SLaks I assigned something a value and then later it was null (as in nothing), regardless it turned out to be because a mishap by my last-night sleepy self.

Comment: There's an [implementation on Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#C.23).

Comment: @GustavBertram Thanks, but no thanks. :) More to gain from doing it on my own. Finished the compression part now, just need to write decompression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your nodeList object in array or a List? If it is a list, then nodeList.RemoveAt(0) causes the node currently located and index 1 to now be located at index 0. so you would need to call

```
nodeList.RemoveAt(0); 
nodeList.RemoveAt(0);
```

instead of

```
nodeList.RemoveAt(0); 
nodeList.RemoveAt(1);
```

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SLaks True. I was biased by the terrible title.